# Symmetricds error Unable to reload rows for missing foreign key data for table 'ir_model_fields'

Tags: symmetricds

I'm using symmetricds and i have this problem Unable to reload rows for missing foreign key data for table 'ir_model_fields'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're syncing all tables that are referenced through foreign keys.

Comment: Hi, thanks
i have problem ir_model too but this tablet doesn't have any relationship

this is the error

2017-04-07 09:03:37,611 WARN [maestro] [DataService] [qtp674270306-125] Unable to reload rows for missing foreign key data for table 'ir_model', parent data not found.  Using sql='select "id", "model", "name", "state", "info", "transient", "create_uid", "create_date", "s '[null]'

When i have this problem the sync stop completely and i need to delete the sym_data  

How i can avoid this ?

Comment: Table ir_model also has foreign keys. Otherwise you wouldn't be having this error